# How can we use or condition in a multiple relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to run a query to get any projects that a user is an owner of or a member of. A project can have one user as an owner (belongs_to) or many users as a member (has_and_belongs_to_many).

The following doesn't give an error but it doesn't work correctly:

```
Project.joins(:members).where(user: current_user).or(Project.joins(:members).where(:users  => { :id => current_user.id })).order('updated_at DESC')
```

The following gives the `ArgumentError Exception: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]` error:

```
Project.joins(:user).where(user: current_user).or(Project.joins(:members).where(:users  => { :id => current_user.id }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to resort to using multiple queries, these `or` statements can be somewhat tricky. Maybe something like this.

```
ids1 = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id).ids
ids2 = Project.joins(:members).where(users: { id: current_user.id }).ids

Project.where(id: [ids1, ids2].flatten)
```